# How to write a bash script to open multiple files in Vim using splits and tabs?

Tags: bash, vim

I am trying to automate some manual labor, using a bash script. Basically I open multiple files with Vim in 1 terminal-window (and only one terminal-tab), using several splits, vsplits and tabs. I will now describe a general case to explain what I usually do manually.

I use 3 tabs (referring from here on as A, B and C) and I open 4 files in each tab in a 2x2 layout:

```
bash:~$ cd ~/Workspace/
bash:~/Workspace$ vim A11.m
:vsplit A12.m
:hsplit A22.m
"move cursor to A12.m"
:hsplit A21.m
:tabedit B11.m
:vsplit B12.m
:hsplit B22.m
"move cursor to B12.m"
:hsplit B21.m
:tabedit C11.m
:vsplit C12.m
:hsplit C22.m
"move cursor to C12.m"
:hsplit C21.m
```

What I would like to create is a shell script into which the file names and location(s) are hard-coded, which upon execution would do all the above. Can anyone suggest to me an approach which would make this possible (if possible at all)? Thanks in advance!

ps: In my .vimrc I have added some configurations such that :split opens the new file beneath (instead of above) the current file and :vsplit opens the new file to the right (instead of to the left).

Comment: You can specify Vim commands from the command line using the `-c` or `--cmd`  flags, but to achieve what you want I think it would be much simpler to write a Vimscript function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least four ways to do this:

1. ```
   vim -s <(echo $':vsplit A12.m\n:hsplit A22.m\n…')
   ```
2. ```
   vim -S <(echo $'vsplit A12.m\nhsplit A22.m\n…')
   ```

   it is similar to what @romainl, but you create the script by yourself and do not use any file besides the bash script itself (can be as well just an alias or a line in history). It is possible to use HERE-strings in bash, they are more readable:

   ```
   vim -S <(cat <<<EOF
   vsplit A12.m
   hsplit A22.m
   …
   EOF
   )
   ```
3. ```
   vim -c 'vsplit A12.m | hsplit A22.m | …'
   ```

   You can have multiple `-c` keys which are run in sequence, but not more then ten thus you have to join commands in one `-c` with bar.
4. Instead of a bash script use vim one:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/vim -S
   vsplit A12.m
   hsplit A22.m
   …
   ```

   . Then you can `chmod +x` it and run like any other executed file. Vim treats `#!` as a comment leader just for that reason.

Comment: Thank you very much ZyX. You actually answered my question. Although I must confess that the approach romainl suggested is very tempting because it requires no work at all. All in all thank you for answering my question directly.

Answer (score 8):

What about `:help mksession`?

1. Set up all your tabs and windows.
2. Do `:mks /path/to/mysession.vim` to save the current settings and layout into `/path/to/mysession.vim`.
3. Quit Vim.
4. Open Vim with `$ vim -S /path/to/mysession.vim` to restore your workspace.

---

You can also restore your session with `$ vim -c "so /path/to/mysession.vim"` or, when Vim is already runing, with `:so /path/to/mysession.vim`.

Comment: Thank you very much romainl. Although I requested a different approach with my question, this approach is truly very simple.