# how to launch vim opening 4 files in 2 tabs, with 2 windows in each

Tags: vim, command-line, tabs

I know how to open all files each in one tab or each in one window, but is it possible to make them open in a combination of tabs/windows?

I am using gvim 7.3

Comment: Is it something you do often with the same files? Anyway, [take a look over there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12409629/546861).

Comment: yes, same files most of the time...your answer there will work, this could be close as duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the notion of tab pages backwards.  From `:h tabpage`:

> A tab page holds one or more windows.

I'm not sure if it's what you want, but you can create two tabs each with two windows through liberal use of `-c` on the command line:

```
gvim -p2 first.txt third.txt -c "sp second.txt" -c "tabn" -c "sp fourth.txt"
```

This leaves the focus on the 4th file.  You can rearrange the arguments (or add more) if you want to do something different.  Also note that gvim will confusingly tell you that it's only opening two files.

Comment: how did I have tabs backwards? I want two tabs, each tab has two windows, one buffer in each window. I think I could do it with /c, as you propose

Comment: Hmmm.  You're right now that I re-read your question.  Maybe I was the one who had the notion of tabs backwards and simply projected it onto you. :)

Comment: actually, this works best, using a session did some weird stuff. I am just struggling  with having windows same size after full screening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:[count]tab {cmd}` ([tab-page-commands](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#tab-page-commands)) in combination with `:[n]sbnext [N]` ([buffer-list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#buffer-list)) as follows:

`vim file1 file2 file3 file4 +sbn +"tab sbn" +sbn`

Just add more `+"tab sbn" +sbn` for more files. If you want to split vertically, replace `+sbn` by `+"vert sbn"`.